# How to estimate the variance of several populations when every population mean and variance is different?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

I'm currently using the [Pooled Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance) method, but in my case I cannot assume that every population variance is the same.

Is there a method for these cases ?

Comment: Then you should estimate each variance separately

Comment: I'm already doing that, now I need to come up with the overall variance and the information I have is every subpopulation element count, variance and mean.

Comment: You cannot end up with one estimate for an overall variance unless you assume that all the elements come from the same population. Perhaps I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try. Find estimates of $E[X^2]$ for each group and then an overall estimate using a weighting scheme by group count. Do the same for the mean. Then estimate the overall variance with $$\hat \sigma^2=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2.$$

Comment: On your comment: I think you are right, pooled variance is like a mean variance rather than the variance of the pooled population.